# Eager loading with cascading comboboxes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity framework application where I have a one to many relationship between Customer and Projects.  The data is accessed in cascading combo boxes.  I was originally using lazy loading and everything worked.  Since I have to serialize my data now I need to load my data another way.  I would like to use eager loading but I am not exactly sure how to implement it in my situation.  In the Projects property I am trying to access with the following:

```
 var a = context.Customers.Include("Project");
            projects = (ObservableCollection<Project>)a;
```

but am getting a convert type error.  Would anyone have any suggestions for me to access the Products data? Thanks.

```
public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    RevisionModelContainer context = new RevisionModelContainer();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();            
    }
 private ObservableCollection<Customer> customers;
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
    {
        get 
        {         
            return customers;            
        }            
        set
        {
            customers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Customers");               
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Project> projects;
    public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects 
    {
        get
        {
            var a = context.Customers.Include("Project");
            projects = (ObservableCollection<Project>)a;
            return projects;             
        }
        set
        {
            projects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Projects");
        }
    }

 private Customer selectedCustomer;
    public Customer SelectedCustomer
    {
        get { return selectedCustomer; }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                selectedCustomer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer");
                this.Projects = selectedCustomer.Projects;
                OnPropertyChanged("Projects");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Seleceted Customer: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private Project selectedProject;
    public Project SelectedProject
    {
        get { return selectedProject; }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                selectedProject = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProject");
                this.Programs = selectedProject.Programs;
                OnPropertyChanged("Programs");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Selected Project: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your "Projects" and "Customers" properties should be of type `IEnumerable<Project>` and `IEnumerable<Customer>` respectively.  You do not need to cast anything to ObservableCollection.  The only time you need to use ObservableCollections is when the view needs to react to the **content** of the collection changing.  In your case the view only needs to know that the Projects property **value** changed to a different list of projects.

Here's what I mean:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    RevisionModelContainer context = new RevisionModelContainer();

    public ViewModel() 
    {
        Customers = context.Customers.Include("Project");
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<Project> Projects { get; private set; }

    private Customer selectedCustomer;
    public Customer SelectedCustomer
    {
        get 
        { 
            return selectedCustomer; 
        }
        set
        {
            selectedCustomer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer");

            // reset the projects.
            this.SelectedProject = null;
            this.Projects = selectedCustomer.Projects;
            OnPropertyChanged("Projects");
        }
    }

    private Project selectedProject;
    public Project SelectedProject
    {
        get 
        { 
            return selectedProject; 
        }
        set
        {
            selectedProject = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProject");
        }
    }
}
```

from what I can tell about your use case, this should work.  You would only need observable collections if you were dynamically *adding* or *removing* items from the customers, projects or programs collections in your view model like this:  `Projects.Add(new Project());`.

If all you're doing is assigning properties like this `Projects = SelectedCustomer.Projects` there's no need to use an observable collection, you just need to raise the propertychanged event for the property you updated.

Comment: I believe they do need to react.  There are different projects depending on which customer is selected.

Comment: I added more detail to my response- I don't think it was all that clear what I meant initially.

Comment: I am actually dynamically adding and removing items from the collections.  Sorry I did not mention that earlier.  I didn't it would conflict with my problem.

Comment: ok I can update the answer to reflect this info but I don't think it will be what you are looking for.  there is no way to cast `selectedCustomer.Projects` to an `ObservableCollection<Project>` or `INotifyCollectionChanged` even.  You'll need to create a new observable collection and dump the contents of selectedCustomer.Projects in there which means your adds/removes won't be reflected in the actual entity collection.

Comment: `selectedCustomer.Projects` is likely of type `EntityCollection<Project>` and `EntityCollection<T>` looks like this:

`EntityCollection<TEntity> : RelatedEnd, ICollection<TEntity>,  Enumerable<TEntity>, IEnumerable, IListSource where TEntity : class`

Comment: So is there a better way to load data than eager loading?